# Java Storing sequence of functions run

Tags: java, arrays, function

i have a program in java and what i want to do is somehow store all the functions that have been run whilst the program ran. but i can not seem to find anything on this matter. Also then have to find out which of the function has been ran the most amount out time.

my thought was that i could make an array, assign each function to have a variable with a name of the function and then everytime it is run return that char into the array, and print out the array at the end. But i dont know how to go about storing them in different arr[i] i's everytime same function is ran, also im not sure how i would then find the one that was ran most, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could use a logger and evaluate the log file afterwards. The advantage is that you can have different log levels depending on the information you want and if you turn off the logger the program still runs as before.

Comment: You can use a `HashMap` to store the method names + their run counts. Create a method for noting down this information and call it at the beginning of each method. You can pass the method name (String) as argument to the above logging method.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with storing the invocation counts? Why do you want to see which are called the most often?

Comment: the reason i need it to do it is as its the last part of my uni assignment, im programming a robot that does some stuff and then i have to follow thru all of its actions and see which one occured the most. we have not covered anything as such so i am unsure how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend is creating a boolean for each method, and at the beginning of the method, set the boolean to true. Then create a save method using the java.io class and save the boolean name and value to the file.

EDIT
I just realized i put boolean instead of integer. Have an integer for each method and do integer++ for each method run.

Answer (score 0):

[AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is great for something like this.

See https://dzone.com/articles/monitoring-performance-spring for an example that uses the Spring AOP library.

Answer (score 0):

i tried a program that may help you or not. i created a Interceptor class which will print out the details you may need. You didnot mention about any frameworks, so i just gave you an example program with plain old java.
This approach also offers flexibility to print all the details at the end of program execution.

```
public class Test {
    public void demoMethod() throws InterruptedException{

        Intercept.printMethodStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intercept.printMethodName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Intercept.printMethodEndTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Test().demoMethod();
    }
}

class Intercept{
    private static Long startTime;
    private static Long endTime;
    public static void printMethodName(String methodName){
        System.out.println("Current method name: "+methodName);
    }
    public static void printMethodStartTime(Long time){
        startTime = time;
        System.out.println("Method started at "+startTime);
    }
    public static void printMethodEndTime(Long time){
        endTime = time;
        System.out.println("Method ended at "+endTime);
        printMethodRunTime();
    }
    public static void printMethodRunTime(){
        System.out.println("Method ran for "+((endTime-startTime)/1000)+" seconds");
    }
}
```